# putting an img tag inside of an a href tag causes a border around image in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have some HTML where I have img tags inside of an  href tag to use as a button. Everything works fine except that when I open it in IE, I get a border around the img tag.

Here's some code:

```
<a href="javascript:changecolor(1)" title="Click Again to Change Color" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none"><img src="button.png" width="25" height="25" style="margin-top:600px;" /></a>
<a href="javascript:changecolor(2)" title="Click Again to Change Color" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="button.png" width="25" height="25" style="margin-top:600px;" /></a>
<a href="javascript:changecolor(3)" title="Click Again to Change Color" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="button.png" width="25" height="25" style="margin-top:600px;" /></a>
<a href="javascript:changecolor(4)" title="Click Again to Change Color" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="button.png" width="25" height="25" style="margin-top:600px;" /></a>
<a href="javascript:changecolor(7)" title="Click Again to Change Color" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="button.png" width="25" height="25" style="margin-top:600px;" /></a>
<a href="javascript:changecolor(6)" title="Click Again to Change Color" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="button.png" width="25" height="25" style="margin-top:600px; text-decoration:none" /></a>
```

How can I get rid of the blue border, which only appears in IE?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Simple fix, in your stylesheet create a style similar to this:

```
a img{
border:0;
}
```

In your case, you could update your style to include some of the inline styles you have in your HTML. For example, your stylesheet would be updated to:

```
a{
cursor:pointer;
text-decoration:none
}

a img{
margin-top:600px;
}
```

Comment: that worked great, however I have another minor problem again only in IE, I have a top-margin set on some of my images and when I click them there is a grayed out striped box around the size of the margin when I click it, any ideas how to remove that?

Comment: Sounds like it could be the change colour JS your implementing. Try removing the margin-top from the img and applying to the a tag instead. If that doesn't work - Can you supply a live link or an screen grab?

Comment: You might have to add the style 'display:inline-block' to the 'a' class to get it to recognise the margin as well.

Comment: @user541597, if this answer worked great, you may want to check it as the accepted answer.  That will tell other users that they don't need to try to solve your problem.  As far as your other question, you will get best results by asking it as a new question.

Comment: Like @amccormack said, you might be better off marking this answer as correct if it worked for you and then posting another question for the new glitch - that way you will have a wider audience to help with this latest issue.

Comment: I tried setting the margin-top to the a tag but it forces me to leave at least one with margin-top on the img tag otherwise the buttons move to the top.  I also tried to inline block but it didn't work.

Comment: Post the issue as a new question including either a live link or a sample of the HTML and CSS up on jsfiddle.net and I'm sure you get lots of people trying to help.

Answer (score 12):

Add border="0" attribute to the img tag

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the minor issue with Internet Explorer and the grayed box around the anchor tag - this is outline. To hide the outline box you can use following CSS:

```
a img{outline:none;}
```